# Making only a part of <h5> red using HTML CSS

Tags: css

I would **only** like to make the strSalePrice **red**. How can I do that?

```
<h5><s>€<?php echo ($datas[19]['intPrice']); ?></s><b> €<?php echo ($datas[19]['strSalePrice']); ?> </b></h5>
```

Result:
€24.99 €19,99

*NOTE: 24.99 is crossed out.*

Comment: Wrap it in a `<span>`. Style the span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `<span>`tag to mark up the part you want and add style to it.

```css
.make_red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<h5><b>$ <span class="make_red"> Your_sale_price</span> </b></h5>
```

Comment: That would also style the Euro symbol

Comment: @Turnip, fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You can use html inline style:

```php
<h5>
  <s>€<?php echo ($datas[19]['intPrice']); ?></s>
  <b>€<?php echo '<span style="color:red">'.($datas[19]['strSalePrice']).'</span>' ?> 
  </b>
</h5>
```